# Derive $ΔS = Nk\ln(V/V_0)$ using fundamental equations of thermodynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility, adiabatic

I am considering a system with an ideal gas undergoing an adiabatic expansion. The initial volume is $V_0$ and final is $V$.
From this, How do I derive $\Delta S = Nk\ln(V/V_0)$ using fundamental equations of thermodynamics?

I know that $dQ=0$ as it is adiabatic, but im also a bit confused because doesnt that also mean $dS=0$ as $dS=dQ/T$? so why is it so significant to find $\Delta S = Nk\ln(V/V_0)$ instead? Someone please help.

Comment: You need to specify whether the process is reversible or irreversible

Comment: I down-voted because "adiabatic expansion" alone is not enough information to calculate $\Delta S$: it could be *anywhere* between $\Delta S=0$ and $\Delta S = k N \ln(V/V_0)$, depending on the amount of work that is extracted. You seem to know the answer, which means you also have information about the process that you have not given in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here we have an irreversible expansion of an ideal gas which I shall model as the gas being in a one compartment (volume $V_0$) of a container, separated from an evacuated compartment of volume $V_1-V_0$ by a partition, in which a hole is made. After a while, passing through various non-equilibrium states, the gas reaches equilibrium at volume $V_1$.

Since entropy is a function of state, the entropy change, $\Delta S$, depends only on the initial and final states, which are equilibrium states.  $\Delta S$ is therefore the same as would occur in a quasi-static process (all intermediate states being equilibrium states) linking the initial and final states. The quasi-static process needed is isothermal expansion.

Why isothermal? It's because $\delta Q=0$ and $\delta W=0$ at all stages of the irreversible expansion, so there is never any change in the gas's internal energy, $U$. For an ideal gas, this implies no temperature change. So the initial and final states are at the same temperature and lie on the same isothermal. As explained in the previous paragraph, we can calculate $\Delta S$ using a quasi-static isothermal change from initial to final states, for which at all stages, $dU=0$, so,
$$T\ dS=p\ dV=\frac{nRT}V dV$$
As Niall has said in his answer, this is easily solved to give the desired relation:
$$\Delta S=nR\int^{V_1}_{V_0} \frac{dV}V=nR\ln\left(\frac{V_1}{V_0}\right)$$

Comment: There would be no equivalent of your working for the Van der Waals gas because it is not isothermal there. And it would be kind of difficult to justify that the non-quasistatic process will give the same result as the quasistatic process.

Comment: @naturallyinconsistent  (a) I agree that the irreversible expansion of a V der W gas will not be isothermal – the temperature will drop (b) Although I said in my answer that  for an ideal gas we could calculate the entropy change using a reversible isothermal change linking initial and final equilibrium states, my mathematics was based on  = 0 and not on   = 0. (c)  = 0 throughout the irreversible expansion of the V der W gas, and the initial and final states are equilibrium states so we can still in principle calculate Δ from a quasi-static process linking them.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation appears to be for an ideal gas that has experienced an irreversible adiabatic free expansion.  Using classical thermodynamics, the only way we know of to determine the entropy change for a system that experiences an irreversible process is to devise an alternate reversible path between the same initial and final states and calculate $\int{dQ/T}$ for that alternate reversible path.  Of course, to devise such a path, one must first know what the final state is.  The final state is determined by applying the first law of thermodynamics to the system undergoing the irreversible path.  For the free-expansion irreversible path, we know that Q is zero (only for the irreversible path) because the process is adiabatic, and W is zero because the overall enclosure for the gas is rigid.  This tells us the $\Delta U=0$, and, for an ideal gas, this means that T is constant.  So the initial state is $(T, V_0)$ and the final state is $T,V$.

The alternate reversible path does not have to bear any resemblance whatsoever to the actual irreversible path.  It does not even have to be adiabatic.  The simplest reversible path that we can think of between these same two end states is an isothermal reversible expansion, for which $$Q=W=NkT\ln{(V/V_0)}$$Note that neither Q nor W is zero for this path.  No matter.  The entropy change between these same two end states is $$\Delta S=\frac{Q}{T}=Nk\ln{(V/V_0)}$$

Comment: "this means that T is constant" Might it be better to say "this means $\Delta T=0$?

Comment: Yes, that would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The equality $dS = dQ/T$ is only valid for irreversible processes and not, as you are describing, for the free expansion of a gas. Instead, let's look at the  fundamental equation of thermodynamics

\begin{equation}
dU = -TdS + pdV
\end{equation}

If the process is adiabatic and occurs without any transfer of energy (i.e. $dQ=0$ and $dW=0$) then we can use

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
TdS &= pdV \\
&= nRT\frac{dV}{V}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

which is easily solved for the desired relation.

Comment: this gets the correct answer for wrong reasons. during the expansion, p and T arent defined

Comment: "The equality $dS = dQ/T$ is only valid for irreversible processes".  That's not true.

Answer (score -2):

This is one of the reasons why I really think ``adiabatic" should be retired from standard physics lingo. It is pedagogically a headache.

This is adiabatic free expansion. It may have succeeded in not transferring heat, but it is not an *isentropic* process. It is not possible for this to be quasistatic, and thus not possible for it to be reversible. p and T are not well defined during the expansion.

The only way to get the correct answer is to first obtain Sackur-Tetrode entropy formula. You can derive it using ideal gas law.

The initial state is a steady state. All the state functions are well defined then. The process is chaotic and cannot be analysed. The final state is also a steady state, after you wait almost infinite amount of time for things to equilibriate. This means you can find the entropy before and after, and find that the entropy changed.

That means $dS = \bar d Q / T + dS_\text{irrev} $, and this time you saw the irreversible contribution